# Murderer or Murderess

Tags: vocabulary

I think the word "murdere" is masculine and the word "murderess" is feminine.

Is that right to say:

```
     She is murderer.
```

Or:

```
     She is murderess.
```

And does it make difference if both are correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Native Anglophones are increasingly disinclined to make such gender distinctions...

[image] [(Link)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=she%20is%20a%20murderer%2Cshe%20is%20a%20murderess&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=30&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshe%20is%20a%20murderer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshe%20is%20a%20murderess%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cshe%20is%20a%20murderer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshe%20is%20a%20murderess%3B%2Cc0)

...but neither of OP's versions are "correct", because you *always* need an article in this type of construction. If the context is about identifying a *specific* murderer that people are talking about, you could say *"She is **the** murderer/murderess"*, but more commonly and more generally (if you're saying something *about her*) it would be *"She is **a** murderer"*.

Comment: +1 -- you made the answer I was just about to make! Many Americans use the "-er" word without thinking colloquially, or simply don't know that there is a feminine version of the word. There are some hold-overs of very common words with the differentiation that are still in use like actor and actress, but I believe it's not going to be observed much longer, especially with more gender-neutral terms such as "role" showing up.

Comment: @Crazy Eyes: I wasn't aware there's much of a US/UK divide here, though the fast-becoming-outdated *actor/actress* distinction seems much associated with Hollywood to me. But much depends on the specific word-pair. We don't use *adulterer/adulteress* so often these days, and I'd say both words have somewhat outlived their usefulness (for Brits, anyway! :), but perhaps precisely *because* they're rather dated terms, those people who still use them are much more fastidious about observing the gender distinction. *"She's an adulterer"* is not at all common compared to *"She's an adulteress"*.

Comment: I'm fascinated by that spike in the 1910's... Was murdering a popular past-time for women in that time period or something?

Comment: Maybe this http://murderpedia.org/female.F/f/fazekas-julia.htm